# Saving with hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I'm new to hibernate and am trying to play around with it. However, I'm facing a little problem. So I have a kind of massaging app and users can send messages to each other here. Here is the User and Massage class:

```
@Entity(name = "userPojo")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String username;
    private String password;
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
    @JoinTable(name = "user_messages")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private final List<Message> messages = new LinkedList<>();

    // constructor and getters&setters

}

@Entity
public class Message {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int ID;
    private String message;
    private String dateTime;
    @ManyToOne
    private User sender;

    // constructor and getters&setters
    
}
```

now if a sender of a message wants to delete one of his messages I will face this Exception:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: update or delete on table "message" violates foreign key constraint "fkdqkq2exjkook6o3vx26kxnnya" on table "user_messages"
  Detail: Key (id)=(2) is still referenced from table "user_messages".
```

I would appreciate your help to fix this error

Comment: Provide also the rest of the code that loads records from DB and performs delete. Also, shouldn't `Message` have two users (author and recipient)?

Comment: actually, that list of messages that each user has is for their saved messages. To keep the data that you are talking about, I have a field chat that I didn't want to mention here. the problem was that I have to save the message to the database first then the user @MartinDendis

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're facing is a mapping problem, you're saying that a message should have multiple users instead of belong to a single one? Some alternatives to try are removing the ManyToOne from Message or use the "mappedBy" annotation property to designate the relationship owner (Message x User) that is unknown at this point. After that, removing desired items from the parent's collection + save should do the trick.

[This tutorial may also shed some light](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many)